# TSQL Years Below 1000

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get the first day name of a given year.
This is the current code I'm testing with.

```
DECLARE @myDate AS DATE
--SET @myDate = '0999-01-01' --DOESNT WORK
SET @myDate = '1000-01-01' -- WORKS
SELECT @myDate
DECLARE @date AS int = YEAR(@myDate)
SELECT @date
SET @date = CONCAT(CONCAT('0', @date), '0101')
SELECT DATEPART(dw, CONVERT(varchar,@DATE))
```

I've tried concatenating a 0 to the year, as I thought it might not be interpenetrating the year correctly, however the same problem occurs.

According to [Microsoft's Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) I should be able to go to year 1.

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work"??? SET @myDate = '0999-01-01' Works just fine for me.

Comment: Aside: Do you need to know where the date applies so that you can correct for the calendar in use on that particular date? See [Adoption of the Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adoption_of_the_Gregorian_calendar).

Comment: Oh I see what the problem is here. You have your @date variable defined as an int and then you concatenate '0' to the front and expect it to work. An int does not have leading zeros. If you want to manipulate strings you need to work with character data. Change the last variable to varchar(4) instead of int and this whole snippet works fine.

Comment: Also, a slight detour but declaring varchar with no length is not a good habit. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a date literal:

```
SET @myDate = '1000-01-01' -- WORKS
```

But this is not the same thing, because the output of a function can't be a date literal:

```
SET @date = CONCAT(CONCAT('0', @date), '0101')
```

You could try wrapping that in a CONVERT but a better approach would be:

```
SET @date = DATEFROMPARTS(@yearyouwant,1,1)
```

Meanwhile there's nothing wrong with this bit, not sure why you're saying that doesn't work:

```
DECLARE @myDate as Date
SET @myDate = '0999-01-01'
PRINT @myDate
```

BUT your script does have @date in it twice with different types, once as an int and once as a date, so thats not going to work.

All in all I think you want something like

```
DECLARE @myDate AS DATE
SET @myDate = '1983-09-07' 
SELECT @myDate
DECLARE @yearValue AS int = YEAR(@myDate)
SELECT @yearValue
DECLARE @adjustedDate as DATE
SET @adjustedDate = DATEFROMPARTS(@yearValue,1,1)
SELECT DATEPART(dw, @adjustedDate)
```